# why my page is not stable?

Tags: html, css

I have a page structured as a hidden table ( I tried using divs only, but it's not suitable to me).. and I have links in the SECOND cell (let's call it A) that call links in the FIRST cell (let's call it B) that will call a div section under the SECOND cell (a paragraph under A) all within the same row..

everything is going fine, but when I hit A, the B links showed fine but make the page shifts up.. and when I hit the button that hide B the page shifts back to the original place..

I searched a lot about this.. most of answers was all about scroll.. I did it just in case (even though my problem is in shifting up and down not right and left).. but I still have the problem..

any suggestion please?

thanks in advanced..

UPDATE:
I really did plenty of research.. but seems nobody has faced the problem I'm facing ..
PLus, I tried to manipulate my code for two days.. plz don't misjudge me :(

the main table:

```
.myTable
{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  float : left;        
  table-layout: auto;   
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid black; */
}

/*.myTable td {
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: ;
  overflow: hidden;
} */
.myCenter
{
  width: 90%;
}
.tLeft
{
  width: 150px;
}
.myLeft
{

    text-align:left; /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */          
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;    /*
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;             */
    visibility: hidden;display: none; 
    /*left:5px; 
    border: 3px solid green;  */

}
.myLeft:target
{

    text-align:left; /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */          
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    visibility:visible;
    float:left; /* no such thing as float center !!!*/
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -43px;  
    /*left:5px;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/    
}

.myLeft > ul.menuLeft
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block; /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */      
    float: left;        
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.myLeft > ul.menuLeft > li > a
{
    color: #580000; /* #7a7883;  /* tabs titles */
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid grey;   /* #3333FF border of the tabs */
    margin:2px;  
    width: 150px;       /* Width of the tabs */

    font-size:15px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;

    border-top-left-radius:5px;   
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;  
      -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px;    
      -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;    
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
      -moz-user-select:none;
    cursor:hand;    

}

.myLeft > ul.menuLeft > li > a:hover
{     
    color: white;   
    cursor:hand;     
}

.myLeft > ul.menuLeft > li > a:focus
{  
    color: #f5f9fc;  

}

.myLeft > ul.menuLeft > li:target > a
{
    cursor:default;
... 
}
.myLeft > ul.menuLeft > li:target > div
{
    display:block;
}
```

tabs:

```
.tabs
{
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    text-align:left; /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */        
    width: 100%;   
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/

}
.tabs ul.menu
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline; /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */
   /* width:570px;  
    /*  min-width:570px;  
      max-width:800px;     
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.tabs ul.menu > li
{
    display:inline;
    float:none; /* no such thing as float center !!!*/
    vertical-align: bottom;   
   /** border: 1px solid yellow;  
    cursor:hand;                */

}
.tabs > ul.menu > li >  a
{
    color: #580000; /* #7a7883;  /* tabs titles */
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #f1f3f4;   /* #3333FF border of the tabs */
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;  
    /*width: 25%;*/       /* Width of the tabs */

    font-size:15px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;

    border-top-left-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius-topleft:4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius-topright:4px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    cursor:hand;    
      /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#3333FF));
    /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3333FF, #fff);  /* Firefox 3.6+ */   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3333FF, #fff);
    /* IE 10 */ background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3333FF, #fff);  /* Opera 11.10+ */  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3333FF, #fff);    
}

.tabs ul.menu > li > a:hover
{     
    color: white;   
    cursor:hand;     
}
.tabs ul.menu li > div
{    
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
     width:98%;  
    /* max-width:700px; 
     min-height:230px;  */
    left:0; 
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;         
}
/*.tabs ul.menu > li > div > p
{
    border:1px solid #f1f3f4;      
    background-color: #f5f9fc;  
    width: 99%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;  
    color: #65636e;
    font-size:12px;   
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;       
    min-height:200px;

}  */
.tabs ul.menu > li > a:focus
{  
    color: #f5f9fc;  

}

.tabs ul.menu > li:target > a
{
    cursor:default;
         /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f1f3f4), to(#8A0808));

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8A0808, #f1f3f4);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8A0808, #f1f3f4);

  /* IE 10 */                                     
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8A0808, #f1f3f4);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8A0808, #f1f3f4);  
}

.tabs ul.menu li:target > div
{
    display:block;
}
```

the Content:

```
<!-- content -->
<div class="content" style="height:350px; width:760px; ">
  <div class="tabs"  style="height:390px;"> <!-- Tabs --> 
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="item-1"> <!-- item-1 -->        
      <a href="#left-1">Meetings</a>                        <!-- #f5f9fc --> 
       <div style="display:block; border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; padding:10px; margin:0;  height:310px;">
          <h3 class="insideh"> Welcome </h3>
          <p  class="cl" style="font-size:18px; font-style: italic; padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px; ">
            Welcome welcome welcome <br>
            Please, enjoy the site and feel free to send us any comments you have.<br><br> Thank you.. 
          </p>
       </div> <!-- End of Welcome Div -->   
       <div style=" border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; padding:10px; margin:0; height:310px;"  id="#item-1"> <!-- 222 --> 
        <div class="col" style="width:700px; display:inline;   ">  <!-- 111 -->
          <ul>           
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2009.php">Meetings 2009</a> </li> 
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2010.php">Meetings 2010</a> </li> 
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2011.php">Meetings 2011</a> </li> 
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2012.php">Meetings 2012</a> </li>  
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2013.php">Meetings 2013</a> </li>  
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="">Miscellaneous</a> </li>
          </ul>
         </div> <!-- /111 -->     
      </div> <!-- end of Content #1 -->  <!-- /222 -->  
    </li> <!-- end of item-1 -->
    <li id="item-2">
      <a href="#left-2">Educational Materials</a>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; padding:10px; margin:0; height:310px;" id="#item-2"> <!-- 222 -->
        <div class="col" style="width:700px; display:inline;"> <!-- 111 -->
          <ul>           
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2009.php">Our Books</a> </li> 
                <ul>           
                  <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2009.php"> Books</a> </li> 
                  <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2010.php"> Society</a> </li> 
                  <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2011.php">Guidlines</a> </li> 
                </ul>   
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2010.php"> Society</a> </li> 
            <li> <a class="alLink" href="aec2011.php">Guidlines</a> </li> 
          </ul>               
        </div>  <!-- /111 -->
      </div> <!-- end of Content #2 -->  <!-- /222 -->
    </li> <!-- end of item-2 -->
    <li id="item-3">
      <a href="#item-3">Event Calender 2013</a>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; padding:10px; margin:0; height:310px;" id="#item-3">  <!-- 111 -->
        <div class="col">
            <h3 class="insideh"> Date </h3>                 <p  class="cl" style="font-size:16px;">
            Jan 12th, 2013 <br>
            Apr 30th, 2013 <br> 
            Jul 10th, 2013 <br>                             </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="col">                                                        
            <h3 class="insideh"> Topics </h3>               <p  class="cl" style="font-size:16px;">                 
                              </p>                
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end of Content #3 -->  <!-- /111 -->
    </li> <!-- end of item-3 -->
    <li id="item-4">
      <a href="#item-4">AEC Members</a>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; padding:10px; margin:0; height:310px;"  id="#item-4">  <!-- 111 -->
       <h3 class="insideh"> Our Speaker Members </h3>

      </div> <!-- end of Content #4 --> <!-- /111 -->
    </li> <!-- end of item-4 -->         
    <li id="item-5">
      <a href="#item-5">Gallery</a>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f1f3f4; background-color: #3333FF; width: 99%; padding:10px; margin:0; height:310px;"  id="#item-5">  <!-- 111 -->

       <!--<?php /*include("gal1.html");  */?> -->   
      </div> <!-- end of Content #5 --> <!-- /111 -->
    </li> <!-- end of item-5 -->            
  </ul>     
  </div> <!-- end of Tabs -->         
</div>  <!-- end of content -->
```

the index:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">  
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=2.0" />
      <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/text.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
      <link href="css/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
      <link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
     <?php include 'counter.php' ?>  



  <title>The Echo Club</title>
  <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/imgs/icon.png" />
  </head>
  <body style= "overflow: scroll;">

<table class = "myTable">
  <tr> <!-- first row ****** Header SECTION ****** -->
      <?php include("htmls/header.html");  ?> 
  </tr> <!-- *** End of first row *** -->

  <tr> <!-- second row ****** Top NAVIGATION ******-->
      <td colspan = '3'> <!-- 2-first column -->
            <?php $page = 1; include("htmls/topnav.html");  ?>
      </td> <!-- End of 1-first col -->
      <!--<td> <!-- 2-second col ->
      </td> <!-- End of 1-second col ->
      <td> <!-- 2-third col ->
      </td> <!-- End of 2-third col -->
  </tr> <!-- *** End of second row *** -->

  <tr> <!-- third row ****** Search SECTION ******-->
      <td> <!-- 3-first column -->      
        <div class="myLeft"  style="height:300px; width: 150px;"><ul class="menuLeft">
                <li> &nbsp; </li> </ul> </div>    
      </td> <!-- End of 3-first col -->
      <!--<td> <!-- 3-second col ->
      </td> <!-- End of 3-second col -->
      <td colspan="2"> <!-- 3-third col -->          
          <?php include("htmls/search.html");  ?>  
      </td> <!-- End of 3-third col -->
  </tr> <!-- *** End of second row *** -->

  <tr> <!-- fourth row ****** Main SECTION ******-->
      <td> <!-- 4-first column -->
          <?php  include("htmls/leftNav.html");  ?> 
      </td> <!-- End of 4-first col -->
      <td class="myCenter"> <!-- 4-second col -->
          <?php include("htmls/content.html");  ?>        
      </td> <!-- End of 4-second col -->
      <td> <!-- 4-third col -->
          <!-- <iframe style="width:170px;  height:300px; margin: 0 1% 0 1%;"  frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->  
          <img src="imgs/myAD.jpg" />        
          <?php include("htmls/newsLetters.html");  ?> 
      </td> <!-- End of 4-third col -->
  </tr> <!-- *** End of fourth row *** -->

    <tr> <!-- fifth row ****** Sociel Network SECTION ******-->
      <td> <!-- 5-first column -->           
      </td> <!-- End of 5-first col -->
      <td> <!-- 5-second col -->
          <?php include("htmls/social.html"); ?>  
      </td> <!-- End of 5-second col -->
      <td> <!-- 5-third col -->          
      </td> <!-- End of 5-third col -->
  </tr> <!-- *** End of fifth row *** -->

    <tr> <!-- sixth row ****** Footer SECTION ******-->
      <!--<td> <!-- 6-first column ->          
      </td> <!-- End of 6-first col -->
      <td class="myCenter" colspan = '3'> <!-- 6-second col -->
          <?php include("htmls/footer.html");  ?>  
      </td> <!-- End of 6-second col -->
       <!--<td><!-- 6-third col ->
      </td> <!-- End of 6-third col -->
  </tr> <!-- *** End of sixth row *** -->
</table>  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the code side? I mean can you show the code as the description is quite confusing.

Comment: either give in fiddle or specify the code you have made.

Comment: I guess you mean fragment identifiers make your page jump. Do not use them then.

Comment: Even I have the same feeling that it might be using those links as named anchors.

Comment: sorry for not supporting my question with code.. I'll do it within minutes.. please check what I mean here: http://ataa.netau.net/Q/index.php

Comment: thank you all for responding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I got it finally after a long days of hear-ache.. 
I'll list it down for future askers ..

all I had to do, is to contain it in one stable container div .. Like this:

```
<div style="height:350px; width: 150px; "> <!-- Left Container -->
    <div id = "left-1" class="myLeft"  style="height:300px;" > <!-- Tabs --> 
      <ul class="menuLeft"  >
                <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-1" >bla bla..</a> </li> 

      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id = "left-2" class="myLeft"  style="height:300px;" > <!-- Tabs --> 
      <ul class="menuLeft">
                <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-1">bla bla..</a> </li> 
                <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-2">bla bla..</a> </li> 

      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

instead of the following:

```
<div id = "left-1" class="myLeft"  style="height:300px;" > <!-- Tabs --> 
          <ul class="menuLeft"  >
                    <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-1" >bla bla..</a> </li> 

          </ul>
      </div>
      <div id = "left-2" class="myLeft"  style="height:300px;" > <!-- Tabs --> 
          <ul class="menuLeft">
                    <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-1">bla bla..</a> </li> 
                    <li> <a class="alLink" href="#item-2">bla bla..</a> </li> 

          </ul>
      </div>
```

it really shows how newbie I am :s

Answer (score 1):

> ( I tried using divs only, but it's not suitable to me)

Too bad, I'm sure Google doesn't take kindly to poor or outright wrong HTML semantics as they are constantly trying to understand what your content (provided you HAVE content) is about. To put it another way: if you're not going to bother to do it the right way then don't bother to do it at all. You simply should never use `table` elements unless you have tabular data and page layouts is *NOT* tabular data.

But I'm going to try and get you on the right path here. I've created a basic CSS level 1 tutorial for those who do not understand basic layouts using division elements and CSS level 1. A lot of "pros" use things like CSS level 2 position and such, well if you read and practice you'll not only find it is suitable to you though you'll be far ahead of some self-appointed pros. And if you have questions afterwards feel free to ask me. Seriously, you'll be amazingly surprised at just how much you can do when you insist on doing it the right way.

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/nested-divisible-elements

Comment: thank you very much for answering and trying to convince me with the right choice.. it's being 3 months since I'm working on div.. but after all, the client's suggestions made me switch back to the old table method.. cause I already late in delivering the web site (one of the reasons is trying to understand div muck better)..Thank you so much for your offer .. really appreciate it..